# Unnecessary DOM update for dynamic React elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a React project that generates some DOM elements "dynamically" within JSX:

```
<div className='ui form'>
   <h2 className="header">{subtype}</h2>
   {
     subtypes[subtype].fields.map((field) =>
       <div className='field' key={field.name}>
         <label>{field.label}</label>
         <input name={field.name} 
                value={entity[field.name]} 
                onChange={onInputChange}/>
      </div>
      )
   }
</div>
```

For a specific component, the generated input fields don't ever change during the life of the application (only their props change), so it is just a way to generate forms that are actually static.

So it is exactly equivalent to this "static" JSX:

```
<div className='ui form'>
   <h2 className="header">{subtype}</h2>

   <div className='field' key='field1'>
      <label>Field 1</label>
      <input name='field1' 
                value={entity['field1']} 
                onChange={onInputChange}/>
   </div>
   <div className='field' key='field2'>
         <label>Field 2</label>
         <input name='field2' 
                value={entity['field2']} 
                onChange={onInputChange}/>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I used the first code snippet, then the HTML DOM elements get recreated on every change to state / props. If I use the second snippet, then the HTML appears to be unchanged and only the field values are updated (React can detect in the second instance that the virtual DOM elements are still the same, but not in the first instance)

Is there a way for me to create the "dynamic" virtual DOM in the first code example in a way that it can be cached and reused so that React sees it as being the same on each render?

Many thanks

Comment: Wrap it into a component that extends `PureComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `subtypes` coming from? From what I understand you are receiving this in the component's props. If that is the case, you need to store this variable in this component's state. Then, you need to update it's state in it's `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function.

The thing is, your component will only re-render when it's `setState` function is called. Hence, the components will not re-render when it's props change (after it has already been mounted).

```
class SimpleCom extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      subtypes: props.subtypes
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({
      subtypes: props.subtypes
    });
  }
  render() {
    const subtypes = this.state.subtypes;
    return (
        <div className='ui form'>
           <h2 className="header">{subtype}</h2>
           {
             subtypes[subtype].fields.map((field) =>
               <div className='field' key={field.name}>
                 <label>{field.label}</label>
                 <input name={field.name} 
                        value={entity[field.name]} 
                        onChange={onInputChange}/>
              </div>
              )
           }
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks squgeim, i do set state in the way you suggest, and it correctly renders when state changes. React optimises the update of the "real" DOM by detecting changes in the virtual DOM. My problem is that when I dynamically generate elements in render(), then their corresponding HTML elements get recreated in the "real" DOM on each render() even when they haven't changed. When I statically define them, then the elements are not deleted and replaced. This leads to unwanted / unnecessary changes going on in the real DOM. Can I avoid these unnecessary updates in the real DOM?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean with "dynamically". What exactly are you doing? Is the `subtypes` list being changed in the parent? How much are the changes?

Comment: In my first listing, I create virtual DOM elements (input fields) based on an array of field types. That is what I refer to as "dynamically". In the second I show the equivalent of writing out the resultant JSX more verbosely.

Comment: In practice I only know the fields in my form at runtime based on a data model defined by subtypes. But the fields for a given form once created, never change. The problem is that each call to render recreates these elements in the virtual DOM, which then causes the real browser DOM to tear down and recreate each field even if nothing has changed in the field. I want to avoid this. Perhaps there is a way to create the virtual DOM portion once and then reuse it in render() rather than create it each time in render